# Fetching values of dynamically generated textboxes and validating all textboxes while submitting using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need help in fetching values of dynamically generated textboxes.
Although I found solutions but seems I am unable to follow it.

What I am trying to achieve:
1.Create textbox with help of Add Button.
2.Delete textbox with Remove Button.
3.Fetch entered values in textboxes.
4.Validate entered values in textboxes
  No two textbox should contain same values(not even in upper/lower case).

I am stuck at 3 and 4th requirement.

Below is my code what I am trying.

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var counter=0;

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".addCF").click(function(){
            $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom DB</label></th><td><input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue' + counter + '" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp; <input type="button" name="remCFName" class="remCF" value="Remove"></td></tr>');

            counter++;

            alert("Value " +counter);
        });


        $("#customFields").on('click','.remCF',function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();

            counter--;
            alert("Value_New " +counter);
        });

        $(".getButtonValue").click(function () {
        var msg ='';
        for(i=0; i<=counter; i++){
          msg += "\n customFieldValue #" + i + " : " + $('#customFieldValue' + i).val();
        }
           alert(msg);
         });

    });
    </script>
     </head>
     <body>
      <table class="form-table" id="customFields">
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Custom DB</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp;

                <input type="button" name="addCFName" class="addCF" value="Add">
            </td>

        <td>
           <input type="button" name="getValue" class="getButtonValue" value="Get Value">
        </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Could anyone please help me on this.

Let me know if I am unable to explain my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Use `each()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your working code

1st text box was not getting involved in loop because of different id..

http://jsfiddle.net/xvRpv/

```
 $(".getButtonValue").click(function () {
    var msg ='';
    for(i=0; i<=counter-1; i++){
      msg += "\n customFieldValue #" + i + " : " + $('#customFieldValue'+i).val();
    }
       //alert($('#customFieldValue1').val());
        alert(msg);
     });
```

Comment: Hi,I am facing one problem..when I am trying to fetch the value after deleting row/s then I am not getting the correct values..Could you please help on this

Comment: but in fiddle its working fine after removing text box

Comment: Could you please try once like below mentioned steps:1.Add 2 new textbox by using Add button. Step 2.Remove any textbox by using remove button. Step 3.Now get the value using get value button...It is showing undefined..Please let me know if it's not replicating for you.

Comment: Sorry but i not getting your question... will you please give me the steps.

Comment: 1.First Add few new textbox using add button in the fiddle 2.now remove one or two textbox using remove button 2.Try fetching the value of remaining texboxes using get val button....It's not giving the correct data..Please let me know if still it's not replicating at your end

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$(".getButtonValue").click(function () {
  $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
    console.log("Input box" + i + " contains " + this.value);

    // Validation here
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**

With validation:

```
$(".getButtonValue").click(function () {
  var textboxValues = [];

  $("input[type=text]").each(function(i){
    var fieldVal = (this.value === "")? "blank" : this.value;
    console.log("Field " + i + " contains " + fieldVal)

    if(fieldVal !== "blank"){
      textboxValues.push(this.value.toLowerCase());

      if ($.inArray(fieldVal, textboxValues) != -1){
        alert("Field " + i + " contains a duplicate value!");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help..I am trying to implement the validation

Comment: I edited my post to add validation. Isn't it working?

Comment: Sorry..seems I am not able to incorporate the changes in my code..I am trying..will let you know shortly..Thanks again for helping me on this.

Comment: Ya validation is working ..but could you please help me with few issues..it's always showing Field contains duplicate values although it is not..viz.Field 0 contains A,Field 0 contains a duplicate value.. Field 1 contains B,Field 1 contains duplicate value...Sorry if I am not able to follow you properly

Comment: Hi,Thanks .It's working for all scenario except one case.I have posted it in new question... here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024796/issue-in-converting-to-lower-case-in-jquery-while-fetching-values-from-dynamic-t

Comment: @ Jack Zelig:I need your help in fixing an issue.Below is the link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399554/how-to-fetch-save-value-when?noredirect=1#comment32278572_21399554 Could you please suggest some solution..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate.Hope u might get some idea on this :)

```
$('.code').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        //console.log($(this).val()); //Gets you each fields value
        $('.code').not($this).each(function(){
               if ( $(this).val()==$this.val()) {duplicate=true;}
        });
});

 if(duplicate) {
     alert('entries are similar');
  }else{
     alert('all entries different')
  }
```

I have made a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/82qC8/

Comment: Thank you very much...It's working..I am trying to modify it so that I can validate case sensitive text also..