# Issue In Converting to lower Case in JQuery while fetching values from dynamic textbox

Tags: jquery

Thanks to all who helped me in solving last problem.
I am facing one problem in validation.
Scenario:
When I am entering any uppercase letter in textbox it is showing that word as duplicate value although it is not.

In other scenario it is working fine.
Below is my complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var counter = 1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".addCF").click(function () {
        $("#customFields").append('<tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Database Mode</label></th><td><input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue' + counter + '" name="customFieldValue[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> &nbsp; <input type="button" name="remCFName" class="remCF" value="Remove"></td></tr>');

        counter++;

        // alert("Value " +counter);
    });


    $("#customFields").on('click', '.remCF', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();

        counter--;
        //alert("Value_New " +counter);
    });



    $(".getButtonValue").click(function () {
        var msg = '';
        var textBoxes = $('.code');
        for (i = 0; i <= counter - 1; i++) {
            msg += "\n customFieldValue #" + i + " : " + $(textBoxes[i]).val();
        }
        alert(msg);
    });


    $(".getValidation").click(function () {
        var textboxValues = [];
        var msg = "";
        $("input[type=text]").each(function (i) {
            var fieldVal = (this.value === "") ? "blank" : this.value;
            if (fieldVal == "blank") {
                alert("Database Mode Field is Blank");
                //alert("Field " + i + " contains " + fieldVal);
                return false;
            }
            if (fieldVal !== "blank") {
                textboxValues.push(this.value.toLowerCase());
                //alert($.inArray(fieldVal, textboxValues));
                if ($.inArray(fieldVal, textboxValues) < i) {
                    msg = msg + " " + fieldVal;
                }
            }
        });

        if (msg != "")
            alert("Duplicates : " + msg);
    });

});     
</script>
         </head>
       <body>
        <div class="Validation">
          <table class="form-table" id="customFields">
            <tr valign="top">
                <th scope="row"><label for="customFieldName">Database Mode</label></th>
                <td><input type="text" class="code" id="customFieldValue0" name="customFieldValue[]" /> &nbsp;
                <input type="button" name="addCFName" class="addCF" value="Add More"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="Validate" class="getValidation" value="Validate"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="getValue" class="getButtonValue" value="Get Value"></td> 
            </tr>
          </table>
         </div>
       </body>

     </html>
```

Could anyone please help me in fixing this issue.
Let me know if my problem details is not enough.

Thanks

Comment: So why are you lowercasing the input value?

Comment: Because in my validation I should not allow user to enter duplicate values..might be in upper case or lower case..i.e User should not able to enter..one and One...

Comment: You mean you type just "X", there is is no just "x" value but that's matched as duplicate value?

Comment: Yes.although user will enter more than one character..However what I am trying to achieve in validation is...1.User should not leave the field blank 2.User should not able to enter duplicate values although if it is case changed..i.e user should not able to enter jQuery and in other textbox JQUERY ..or any other such combination..it can also contain numeric values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a toLowerCase() missing.
This should solve your problem:

```
if ($.inArray(fieldVal.toLowerCase(), textboxValues) < i) {
  msg = msg + " " + fieldVal;
}
```

Comment: Hi ..I need your help ..when I am trying to use the code in my application it is throwing error..I am able to add new textbox but other button like remove and Get value are not working..It gives error message :object does not support this property or method...Please suggest ..I am stuck in this implementation
Below is the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039707/message-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-when-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

should do it this way:

```
$(".getValidation").click(function () {
    var textboxValues = [],
        msg = "";

    $("input[type=text]").each(function (i) {
        var fieldVal = $.trim($(this).val().toLowerCase());
        if (!fieldVal) {
            alert("Database Mode Field is Blank");
            return false;
        } else {
            textboxValues.push(fieldVal);

            if ($.inArray(fieldVal, textboxValues) > -1) {
                msg += " " + fieldVal;
            }
        }
    });

    if (msg.length)
        alert("Duplicates : " + msg);
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w3DjR/

Comment: UW, probably I was a bit late to help you -:)

Comment: :)..anyways I got to learn this approach also...however I think we can modify it little bit..because here in this case it will display all text field values always in the Duplicate alert although if it is not...