# How to Fetch/Save Value when

Tags: javascript

Could you please help me on this issue.

There is one javascript function from where I am populating value based on one dropdown.

Values are getting pouplated fine but when I am trying to save it .It is not getting saved.
most probably because I have decalred value as blank in the second text box.

Please suggest solution.
Below is my sample code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function populatePatchingEnd(){
        var strt = document.getElementById   ("retrofit_maintenanceWindowStart");
        var strtVal = strt.options[strt.selectedIndex].text + ""; 

        var strtTemp = strtVal.substring(0, 2);

        if(strtTemp==18){
                var temp="00:00";
                document.getElementById("retrofit_maintenanceWindowEnd").value = temp;
                var temp=this.value;
                } 
                 else if(strtTemp==19){
                 var temp="01:00";
                 document.getElementById("retrofit_maintenanceWindowEnd").value = temp;
                 var temp=this.value;
                }
                 else if(strtTemp==20){
                 var temp="02:00";
                 document.getElementById("retrofit_maintenanceWindowEnd").value = temp;
                 var temp=this.value;
                }
                 else if(strtTemp==21){
                 var temp="03:00";
                 document.getElementById("retrofit_maintenanceWindowEnd").value = temp;
                 var temp=this.value;

                }
                 else if(strtTemp==22){
                 var temp="04:00";
                 document.getElementById("retrofit_maintenanceWindowEnd").value = temp;
                  var temp=this.value;
                }
                 else if(strtTemp==23){
                 var temp="05:00";
                 document.getElementById("retrofit_maintenanceWindowEnd").value = temp;
                  var temp=this.value;
                }
                 else if(strtTemp==00){
                 var temp="06:00";
                 document.getElementById("retrofit_maintenanceWindowEnd").value = temp;
                  var temp=this.value;
                }
                 else if(strtTemp==01){
                 var temp="07:00";
                 document.getElementById("retrofit_maintenanceWindowEnd").value = temp;
                  var temp=this.value;
                }
                 else if(strtTemp==02){
                 var temp="08:00";
                 document.getElementById("retrofit_maintenanceWindowEnd").value = temp;
                  var temp=this.value;
                }
                 else if(strtTemp==03){
                 var temp="09:00";
                 document.getElementById("retrofit_maintenanceWindowEnd").value = temp;
                  var temp=this.value;
                } 
            else{    
                 var temp=Math.floor((new Number(strtTemp))+6.00)+":00";
                 document.getElementById("retrofit_maintenanceWindowEnd").value = temp;
                  var temp=this.value;
                }

        }

    </script>
```

And below code shows where I need to fetch/save the value which I am getting from above function

```
             <input type="text" style="width: 131px;" id="maintenanceEnd" <f:field  att="dotNetServerProvision.maintenanceEnd" disabled="true" value=""/>
                    </td>
```

Comment: console the value read by strt. Most probably the problem is with the value read contains spaces. Trim this value and then try.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am able to fetch the value but I am unable to store that.Means I have written value="" in the second snippet due to which everytime it is saving blank I guess.How can I get that value which I am am getting in populatePatchingEnd() function

Comment: the reason is the multiple declarations for var temp.